# How can I have sequential execution in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequential

I am iterating over dataframe using df.map having transformation on each row.Now for the below code when I am building my package displayResults is printing results as 0 i.e it is not taking values that were obtained after transformation on each row.I realized that displayResults is running in parallel to map method.How can I make this method call wait for completion of inputDataFrame.map method.Thanks:)

```
class Obj{
  var total=_
  var avail=_
  def MyMethod(inputDataFrame: DataFrame): Unit={
    val finalvalue=inputDataFrame.map(r=>{
       //apply transformations on row
       total=r.getInt(0)+r.getInt(1)
       avail=helper(r)
    })
    displayResults(total, avail)
  }
  displayResults(total: Int, avail: Int): Unit={
    println("Results "+(avail/total))
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at accumulators - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators. Also `map` is a lazy transformer, it is not actually applied unless you do a comsume operation. You need to use `foreach`.

Comment: yes I know accumulators will build output consistently.But my concern is not about the transformations I make on input.I somehow want to wait for completion of my .map method